# Combinatorics question involving a string of numbers fixed inside another string

Tags: combinatorics

A normal six-sided die is rolled sixteen times. Find the probability that the sequence of rolls includes the numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ consecutively and in that order. (e.g. a sequence is $4,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,1,1,3,4,5,6$).

I'm learning inclusion-exclusion atm... so I'm not sure how to apply it if this is applicable.
I know the sample space is simply $6^{11}$.

Comment: How did you gather that the sample space is $6^{11}$? Write your thoughts/work on the description of the question.

Comment: Inclusion Exclusion is fine...to count the strings that do not contain the given block, start with the total (which is not $6^{11}$), subtract those where the block starts at a specific number, then add back those containing two copies of the block.  No need to worry about three copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a subsequence of the $16$-term sequence a *qualifying* subsequence if it consists of $6$ consecutive terms of the full sequence, and has successive values $1,2,3,4,5,6$.

In any $16$-term sequence, there are most two such qualifying subseqences, and if there *are* two, they can't overlap.

If a qualifying subsequence starts at position $k$, we must have $k \in \{1,...,11\}$.

For each $k \in \{1,...,11\}$, there are $6^{10}$ sequences containing a qualifying subsequence starting at position $k$, allowing for all possible choices for the remaining $10$ terms.

But the product $(11)(6^{10})$ is an overcount, since sequences containing two qualifying subsequences are counted twice.

To correct the count we need to subtract the number of sequences containing two  qualifying subsequences.

For each placement of two qualifying subsequences, there are $6^4$ ways of completing the full sequence, allowing for all possible choices for the remaining $4$ terms.

If there are two qualifying subsequences, then the first one must start at a position $k \in \{1,...,5\}$, and for each such $k$, the positions available for the start of the second qualifying subsequence are the $6-k$ elements of  the set $\{k+6,...,11\}$. It follows that there are exactly 
$$\sum_{k=1}^6\;(6-k) = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15$$
valid placements for the two qualifying subsequences.

Thus, to correct the count of $(11)(6^{10})$, we need to subtract $(15)(6^4)$.

Hence, the number of sequences having at least one qualifying subsequence is
$$(11)(6^{10}) - (15)(6^4)$$

so the required probability is
$$\frac{(11)(6^{10}) - (15)(6^4)}{6^{16}}=\frac{171067}{725594112} \approx .002357612847$$